# build an html5 web app to work in BlackBerry using the phonegap build

Tags: cordova, blackberry, phonegap-build

I have developed a html5 jquery mobile application using the phonegap build website. It works fine on Android, iOS and Windows Phone but BlackBerry is not on the list anymore.

I have searched on the net and I didn't find anything. Should I give up the BlackBerry version of my mobile app? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Official word from PGB: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/introduction_supported_platforms.md.html#Supported%20Platforms

Comment: Also, this blog post from PG: http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/02/21/platform-deprecation/

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap build now only supports iOS, Android and Windows Phone 8.

If you wish to build for other platforms, you will need to use Cordova locally on your machine.

This blog post from PhoneGap explains this and the options you have for continued development:
http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/02/21/platform-deprecation/

Comment: Good answer, but right now if we implement what I should do for blackberry or say the same question ask now, what will be the answer..